# Cannot send messages in other channels except General msbot for teams (nodejs)

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have created a bot for teams and added it to a channel (**testChannel1**) as a tab (using a configuration page). I have received a **ConversationUpdate** event to my server. When I try to send message using the context object that I have received in **ConversationUpdate** event the message was sent in **General** channel instead of **testChannel1**. I have added my bot to **testChannel1** but I dont know why the message is sent in **General**. I am also not able to get the channels list using that context object it is throwing error `Error: This method is only valid within the scope of a MS Teams Team.`.

contextActivityObject :- `{
    "membersAdded": [
        {
            "id": "28:[guid]"
        }
    ],
    "type": "conversationUpdate",
    "timestamp": "2020-04-24T12:00:06.7125247Z",
    "id": "f:[guid]",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/",
    "from": {
        "id": "29:[id]",
        "aadObjectId": "[guid]"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "isGroup": true,
        "conversationType": "channel",
        "tenantId": "[guid]",
        "id": "19:aba[id]@thread.tacv2"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "28:[guid]",
        "name": "teststandups"
    },
    "channelData": {
        "team": {
            "aadGroupId": "[guid]",
            "name": "nikhilp",
            "id": "19:aba[id]@thread.tacv2"
        },
        "eventType": "teamMemberAdded",
        "tenant": {
            "id": "[guid]"
        }
    }
}`

The scope I have provided for my bot is `Team`

I would be thankful for any help

Comment: A bot and a Tab are actually separate things, so they're not per se related, other than both being part of your same Teams app in this case (you don't need the Tab at all).

Comment: Separate from the above, please elaborate on how you're trying to get the Channels list?

Comment: Now I am able to get channels list. Before I have created a conversation reference and using that context I tried to fetch channels. This code worked for me ```const context = new TurnContext(adapter, activity);
TeamsInfo.getTeamChannels(context).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err));```

Comment: What I am trying to do is I want to authenticate user to map his bot activity details to the user in my database. So I am trying to use tabs so that I can authenticate user when he is trying to install my bot. Is there any other approach to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've asked a couple of questions, I'll try answer as best as possible. Basically, that Conversation ID (19:aba[id]@thread.tacv2) is unique per channel, so if you're using the "General" channel one, it will for sure go into General.

To find out how to get the channel Ids, have a look at [Get the list of channels in a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#get-the-list-of-channels-in-a-team). That will show you -how- to get the info, but you need to get a trigger in order to be able to make that call. To do that, the best way is to hook into one of the triggers, like receiving a message from a user, or being added to the team. Included in these set of events, are channels being added and deleted. See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/bot-basics?tabs=csharp).

Comment: Can you please tell me How can I send message to a different channel instead of **General**

Comment: I have achieved this by setting ```conversationReference.conversation.id = different channelId```. Please correct me if I did anything wrong

Comment: yes that's correct. I've updated my answer to include details on getting the channel Ids